# Как передать значение из одного класса в другой в KivyMD

Tags: kivy, kivymd

Как в Class2 передать на печать **root.ids.user.text** и **root.ids.password.text**? Помогите внести изменения в код

***main.py***

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
from kivy.config import Config
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

from class2 import Class2


class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDScrollView):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class Main(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        Config.read("myApp.ini")
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_file('file.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        print("\non_start:")
        store = JsonStore('myBackup.json')
        if store.count() > 0:
            for key in store:
                print("\tid = {0}, obj = {1}".format(key, self.root.ids[key]))
                if isinstance(self.root.ids[key], MDTextField):
                    self.root.ids[key].text = store.get(key)['text']
                    print("\t\ttext = ", self.root.ids[key].text)

    def on_stop(self):
        print("\non_stop:")
        store = JsonStore('myBackup.json')
        for key in self.root.ids:
            if isinstance(self.root.ids[key], MDTextField):
                print("\tid = {0}, text = {1}".format(key, self.root.ids[key].text))
                store.put(key, text=self.root.ids[key].text)

    def logger(self):
        self.root.ids.scr1_label.text = f'Привет {self.root.ids.user.text}!'

    def authorization(self):
        self.thread_1 = Class2()
        self.thread_1.start()

Main().run()
```

***class2.py***

```
import threading


class Class2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Class2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self):
        print(f'Логин: {self.parent.root.ids.user.text}')
        print(f'Пароль: {self.parent.root.ids.password.text}')
```

***file.kv***

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>

    MDList:

        OneLineListItem:
            text: "Окно 1"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

        OneLineListItem:
            text: "Окно 2"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"

MDScreen:

    MDTopAppBar:
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        md_bg_color: "blue"
        elevation: 4
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:

        MDScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 1"
                MDBoxLayout:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: 300, 400
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                    elevation: 10
                    padding: 25
                    spacing: 25
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDLabel:
                        id: scr1_label
                        text: "Окно 1"
                        font_size: 40
                        halign: "center"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        padding_y: 15

                    MDTextField:
                        id: user
                        text: ""
                        hint_text: "имя пользователя"
                        icon_right: "account"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 300
                        font_size: 18
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                        mode: "round"
                    MDTextField:
                        id: password
                        text: ""
                        hint_text: "пароль"
                        icon_right: "eye"
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 300
                        font_size: 18
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                        #password: True
                        mode: "round"
                    MDLabel:
                        id: scr1_label_down
                        text: ""
                        font_size: 20
                        halign: "center"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        padding_y: 15
                    MDRoundFlatButton:
                        text: "LOGIN"
                        font_size: 12
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                        on_press: app.authorization(), app.logger()

                    Widget:
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 10

            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 2"
                MDBoxLayout:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: 300, 400
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                    elevation: 10
                    padding: 25
                    spacing: 25
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDLabel:
                        id: scr2_label
                        text: "Окно 2"
                        font_size: 40
                        halign: "center"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                        padding_y: 15
                    MDTextField:
                        id: key
                        hint_text: ""
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 300
                        font_size: 18
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                        mode: "round"

                    Widget:
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 80

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря тому, что в данном коде используется .json файл, я пошел обходным путем и получил значения напрямую из .json файла. И все же, было бы полезно узнать как получать значения из другого класса. Быть может в Kivy есть специальные механизмы для этого....

***class2.py***

```
import json
import threading


class Class2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Class2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self):
        with open('myBackup.json') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        print(data)
        login = data['user']['text']
        print(login)
        password = data['password']['text']
        print(password)
```